# contain condition in R

Tags: r, function, contains

It is requested to give a number of `JobTitles` which contains `'CHIEF'` in a column of `JobTitle`. I know that there are `JobTitles` like `"CHIEF OF DEPARTMENT, (FIRE DEPARTMENT)"`, `"BATTALION CHIEF, (FIRE DEPARTMENT)"`.

But before I want to is number of `JobTitles`, I checked below codes but both are not working.

```
'CHIEF' %in% data

match('CHIEF', data)
```

what I get after I run dput()
[image]

Where is my mistake?
And how I can make it count how many `JobTitles` contain given word?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I get you correctly, but I have data set named ´data´, there i a column named 'JobTitle', seeking a word in that column so I need 'data$JobTitle', right?

Comment: OK, got it, comment deleted.

Answer (score 4):

```
sum(grepl("CHIEF", data$JobTitle, ignore.case=TRUE))
```

This will give you the number of all JobTitle in data than contain the string CHIEF (regardless of case).

The reason your code didn't work is that both match and %in% seek the full string as an element in a vector, that is, they will only identify jobtitles that are just "CHIEF'. grep (or grepl) is the way to identify partial string matches.

Example with made up data:

```
 data=data.frame(JobTitle=c("moose","chief head", "chief moose"))

sum(grepl("CHIEF", data$JobTitle, ignore.case=TRUE))

[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: gives an error as "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables"

Comment: Can you provide a dput() of your data (or a sample of it?) This error doesn't make sense for the code I suggested.

Comment: When I run the dput() it gives NA's

Comment: Run dput(head(data, 10)). What do you get?

Comment: I answered you below